# What does it mean to have a "greater than" sign in a logit function parameter

Tags: logit

I am reading a machine learning paper and at some point they write the likelihood of the observed data using $logit$ function in their model. However, they have a $>$ symbol in the parameter of the logit function, something like $logit(\alpha > uv)$ where $u$ and $v$ are the parameters to learn from the model and $\alpha$ is a positive tuning parameter. I specifically talk about Equation 2 in [this paper](http://bioinformatics.oxfordjournals.org/content/29/13/i89.abst%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bract). I haven't seen such a representation before, and want to learn what this really means. Thanks.

Comment: Which paper? please give a proper reference.

Comment: Please put the reference *in your question*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The equation that you refer to doesn't appear to make sense mathematically. I suspect it is a misprint. You should write to the authors of the article because only they can clarify.

Comment: Theoretically it can make sense (interpreting $\alpha > uv$ as a logical constant with `TRUE=1` and `FALSE=0`) but yes, almost certainly a misprint. Most likely $logit(alpha) > uv$ but I am guessing there.

Comment: Thanks. I asked the authors and they said it was a misprint of the journal. The "greater than" sign should be "times", so it is actually $\alpha uv$.

Comment: @JDL R code and mathematics are not the same thing. Sure, the expression would evaluate in R because of automatic coercion of logical vectors to numeric, but regular mathematical algebra as recognized by the journal has no such coercion, so the published expression is not parsable mathematics.